# How to create database tables in Sql Server Database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am trying to create an Inventory Database.
There are four receipts used in our warehouse, namely

1. Issue Ticket ,Used to Issue items other than spare parts (Vehicles)
2. Shipping Ticket,Used to transfer items to other locations
3. Parts Requisition and Issue Ticket,Used to issue spare parts
4. Receiving Ticket, used to receive items and add to the warehouse inventory

[PartsRequisitionAndIssueTicket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUmb8.jpg)
[ShippingTicket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3NyW.jpg)
[ReceivingTicket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoQ3e.jpg)
[IssueTicket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFJDB.jpg)

The tickets have almost similar structure.

Should I create a different table for each ticket or is there a way to use a single table to store transactions?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score -1):

as i see that these 4 data is different it terms of its structure and metadata i would suggest to create different tables for these info and there should be a primary-foreign relation between these tables to make sure they are consistent. Also I am assuming the new data will mostly be new records and  minor updates to the rows and they evolve.

Keeping it in once single table will not be feasible on a wrong run and query performance will take a hit.